# shifted sheaves

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-space

Consider a sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ a sheaf of functions over the complex projective space. What is the precise definition to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathcal{l})$, for $\mathcal{l}$ an integer. Is it correct to say that sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(\mathcal{l})$ are polynomials of degree $l$?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_bundle. It is not correct to say that, unless you are more specific about the kinds of polynomials you are referring to. It is correct to say that we may identify sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(l)$ with polynomials in $n$ variables of degree $l$, yes.

Comment: The tautological bundle in the article is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(l)$ is obtained by tensoring the tautological line bundle with itself $l$ times (or its dual).